# Running RAM excessive LLMs on Google Colab

Tags: out-of-memory, google-colaboratory, ram, large-language-model

I am trying to run an LLM named `OpenAssistant/oasst-sft-1-pythia-12b` on Google Colabs
The code I have is as follow:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM



MODEL_NAME = "OpenAssistant/oasst-sft-1-pythia-12b"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME)
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
  MODEL_NAME,
)
```

and

```
input_text= """<|prompter|>"A bit of prompt here"<|endoftext|><|assistant|>"""
input_ids = tokenizer(input_text, return_tensors="pt").input_ids



text = model.generate(input_ids, max_length=256).generated_text
print(text)
```

The problem is that the free version of Google Colab offers only 12.7 GB of RAM. But when I run the above code the RAM goes out of memory and the session crashes as the model is too large to fit in RAM.

I tried searching for solution on web. There are scenarios where people are facing similar problem while training a model. So the suggested solution is to use smaller batch sizes.

But when running the model to generate text, It needs to load model in RAM, is there a way around?